# Getting 403 Response from Spring Boot Rest Service on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, raspberry-pi

**My Setup:**

I got a vue frontend which is calling a spring boot rest api.
Locally I run this in separate docker containers and on my local machine everything is working fine.

For testing purpose I got a raspberry pi connected to my router. On this I also run the frontend and the spring boot inside of different docker container.

The only difference between these setups are, that I can't use the `FROM openjdk:11` Image on my raspberry pi as it not support the arm32v7. There I use the `eclipse-temurin:11` container.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  db:
    image: jsurf/rpi-mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'ghp_board'
      MYSQL_USER: 'ghp_board_admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'ghp_board'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "33006:3306"

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    container_name: ghp_board_frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app/ghp_board_frontend
    depends_on:
      - db

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8886:8080"
```

And this my `Dockerfile` for the backend container:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11

COPY ./system/build/libs/system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**What do I want**

The spring boot application got two controller right now (News and Demand) which should provide data to the frontend through an REST API.
Both controller got nearly the same endpoints:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.webjars.NotFoundException;

import javax.lang.model.element.NestingKind;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class NewsController {

    @Autowired
    private final NewsService newsService;
    private JwtAuthenticationService jwtAuthenticationService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/news", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllNews(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newsService.getAllNewsEntries(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/news/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getNews(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(newsService.getNewsEntry(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Post -> receive a new NewsEntry
    @PostMapping(
            path = "/api/v1/news",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createNews(@RequestParam("file") Optional<MultipartFile> file, @RequestParam("newsData") String newsEntryString, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .findAndRegisterModules()
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        NewsEntryDto newsEntryDto = mapper.readValue(newsEntryString, NewsEntryDto.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(newsService.insertNewNewsEntry(newsEntryDto, file), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //Put -> update an existing NewsEntry
    @PutMapping(
            path = "/api/v1/news",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateNews(
            @RequestParam("file") Optional<MultipartFile> file,
            @RequestParam("newsUpdateId") Long newsUpdateId,
            @RequestParam("newsData") String newsUpdateString,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .findAndRegisterModules()
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        NewsEntryDto newsUpdateDto = mapper.readValue(newsUpdateString, NewsEntryDto.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(newsService.updateNewsEntry(newsUpdateId, newsUpdateDto, file), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //Delete -> delete an existing NewsEntry
    @DeleteMapping(
            path = "/api/v1/news/{id}"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNews(@PathVariable("id") Long newsDeleteId) {
        newsService.deleteNewsEntry(newsDeleteId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.system.demand;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.webjars.NotFoundException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class DemandController {

    private DemandService demandService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/demand", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllDemands() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(demandService.getAllDemandEntries(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/demand/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDemandById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(demandService.getDemandById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(
            path = "/api/v1/demand",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> insertNewDemand(
            @RequestParam Optional<List<MultipartFile>> files,
            @RequestParam String demandData
    ) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .findAndRegisterModules()
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        DemandEntryDto demandEntryDto = mapper.readValue(demandData, DemandEntryDto.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(demandService.insertNewDemandEntry(demandEntryDto, files), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handlerNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

**My Problem:**

When I call the GET-Endpoint `/api/v1/news` from  the frontend, I get all entries from the database, so this is working.
The GET-Endpoint `/api/v1/news/{id}` and the POST-Endpoint are also working fine.
But the other Endpoints PUT and DELETE of the NewsController and all Endpoints of the DemandController are receiving the Responsecode `403 - Forbidden`.
I really can't understand why this is the case.

My `WebSecurityConfig` shouldn't have any specification which explain this behavior:

```
package com.example.system.security;

import com.example.system.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntrypoint;
import com.example.system.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationProvider;
import com.example.system.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntrypoint unauthorizedHandler;  // Gibt 403 zurück, wenn nicht authorisiert

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and() // Aktivieren von Cross-Site
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and() // Gibt 403 zurück, wenn nicht authorisiert
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/home")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

And also the headers of the axois call are the same:

```
getNews() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        const header = {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        }

        return axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/api/v1/news", {
            headers: header
        });
    },
    getNewsDetail(id) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        const header = {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        }

        return axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/api/v1/news/" + id, {
            headers: header
        });
    },
    insertNewsEntry(data) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const header = {
            //'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        }

        return axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/api/v1/news", data, {
            headers: header
        });

    },
    updateNewsEntry(data) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const header = {
            //'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        }

        return axios.put(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/api/v1/news", data, {
            headers: header
        });
    },
    deleteNewsEntry(id) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const header = {
            //'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        }

        return axios.delete(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/api/v1/news/" + id, {
            headers: header
        });
    }
```

Does anyone know what I missed here?

Comment: Can you try using `http.cors().and().csrf().disable()...` in your security config?

Comment: @AshishPatil ok :) That worked surprisingly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers, if comments got removed, I suggested to use

`http.cors().and().csrf().disable()...`  instead of `.csrf().disable().cors().and()..` in `configure` method as sequence of use of `cors` & `csrf` were not correct in original post & issue got resolved afterwords.